# Angular `input` element is not getting added as part of `shadow-root (open)`

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, shadow-dom

I am using `Angular10` and my `app-component.ts` looks as below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

I understand that this will create a `ShadowRoot` for Component's Host Element.

Now, I am adding `input` element in the template as below:

```
<div style='text-align: center'>
  <h1>Parent Component</h1>
  <br><br>
  <label>Parent Component: </label>

  <input type='text' #pInput name='myInput' />
  <button (click)='getInfo(pInput)'>Get Info</button>
</div>
```

When I inspect the DOM which is created, I see `shadow-root (user-agent)` added for the `input` element.

My question is why `input` element is not added as part of `shadow-root (open)`?
In which situation, shadow-root (user-agent) is added?

[image]

Comment: you can refer this - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#create

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` has a User-agent (the Browser) created shadowDOM.
Each Browser Vendor implements the `<input>` different.

You can't access or change that shadowDOM.

Same applies to the `<video>`, `<audio>` and other complex Elements.

Create a document with only those Elements and see the (styling) differences in other Browsers.

shadowDOM isn't new technology,
Browsers have implemented complex Elements for ages with shadowDOM (you just did not see it).

The 'new' part is that we can now apply shadowDOM to Elements ourselves.

But only to Elements:

- `article, aside, blockquote, body, div, footer, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5", h6, header, main, nav, p, section, span`
- Or Custom Elements

source: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-attachshadow

There is a setting in Chromium DEV Tools to turn on/off display:

[image]